# JGit FetchCommand

Tags: git, jgit, git-fetch

I understand the concept of Git fetch. I would like to fetch objects through the FetchCommand class in the JGit API.

I have a Git repository. For example `C:\jGit\.git`.

I have cloned this repository. For example: `C:\jGitClone\jGit\.git`.

I have cloned this repository again. For example `C:\Users\user\Desktop\jGitClone\.git`.

Using the JGit API I have a Git class:

```java
Git git = new Git(repository); // this is the cloned repository. C:\jGitClone\jGit\.git
```

How would I set the cloned repository which is on the desktop so when the fetch is called it knows to fetch into the this repository.

I have looked on some websites including the 1 below but still stuck.

[Git fetch failing using jgit: Remote does not have <branchname> available for fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304261/git-fetch-failing-using-jgit-remote-does-not-have-branchname-available-for-fe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed something. in Git/jGit, a local copy is determined by a `path` (like in a file system), and a `remote`, which is a distant repo.

In your case, you want that your desktop cloned repo has a link to your `jGitClone/jGit` repo. So first, if the cloning is already done, then the desktop repo knows about its remote repo. So in your code, you just need to tell where your desktop repo is:

```
Builder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder()
Git repo = builder.setGitDir(new File("C:\Users\user\Desktop\jGitClone.git"))
  .readEnvironment()
  .build()
```

The code might not be directly working (I didn't test it, the doubts I have are on the path to give, and the objects to use: `Builder`, `Git`), but it's based on this answer that I think will help you: [JGit and finding the Head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342152/jgit-and-finding-the-head)

By the way, your question is not that clear : did you already clone everything or is it what you want to do? in your code you mention a `repository` : did you obtain it using code similar to what I suggested? The names you chose are not very clear either : calling a repo jGit, unless it contains jGit source code, sounds a bit clumsy. Plus, give names to your different repos (A,B,C) to have a clearer understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define remote, which tracks the repository that you can fetch commits from, with valina git, you can do:

```
# suppose you have cloned C:\jGitClone\jGit\.git
$ cd C:\Users\user\Desktop\jGitClone\.git
$ git remote add upstream "C:\jGitClone\jGit\.git"
$ git fetch upstream
```

If you would like to try [git24j](https://github.com/git24j/git24j), you can do this in java just like you would do with valina git:

```
Repository remote = Repository.open("C:\jGitClone\jGit\.git");
Repository local = Repository.open("C:\Users\user\Desktop\jGitClone\.git");
// set up remote
Remote upstream = Remote.create(local, "upstream", URI.create(remote.getPath()));
// fetch from remote
upstream.fetch(null, null, "reflog");
```

The two `nulls` are parameters that defines the refspecs to fetch and the options (where you can setup credentials etc).