# git fetch is deleting a new file which is recently pushed in Jgit

Tags: git, jgit

I am adding a new file in remote repository on master branch when i do git fetch instead of fetching new changes it deletes the file which i added 
for example i added 
`abc.txt` in remote repository `(master)`

i am using git.fetch in code before pull `(master)`

but git fetch is deleting the file

```
abc.txt
```

here is my code

```
git.fetch().setRemote("origin").setRefSpecs(new RefSpec("refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master")).call();
```

please guide me what i am doing wrong 
i also looked at this answer 
[JGit FetchCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424825/jgit-fetchcommand)

Comment: _"I am adding a new file in remote repository"_ do we agree that you're adding new file in the same repo where you do the fetch? Also, the added content is not yet committed?

Comment: yes  i am adding the file to the same repo where i am doing the fetch ...in remote repo ............while staying on github website i am adding  a new file and commitng it

Comment: I cannot reproduce in my machine. I think you might mix the notion of pull and fetch. Fetching content from upstream does not change your workspace. So, if a file is added on GitHub directly, fetching content from it won't change anything in your local repo (which makes you think JGit deletes it). You need to "pull" instead.

Comment: i know git fetch will not make  any changes that is exactly what i want ..also i need to use git fetch first and then pull in my use case

Comment: git fetch is working fine in console but not in code please help